# wpf application for video broadcasting

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement, expression-encoder, broadcasting

I have a WPF application for broadcasting video using Microsoft.expression.encoder and framework 4.0, but i got a delay of 15 sec while broadcasting.Is there any suggestion to reduce the delay while broadcasting.

below is the Code

```
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Live; 
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder;

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    try 
    { 
        EncoderDevice video = null; 
        EncoderDevice audio = null;
        GetSelectedVideoAndAudioDevices(out video, out audio);
        StopJob();

        if (video == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        StopJob();
        _job = new LiveJob();

        if (video != null && audio != null)
        {
            //StopJob();
            _deviceSource = null;
            _deviceSource = _job.AddDeviceSource(video, audio);
            _job.ActivateSource(_deviceSource);

            // Finds and applys a smooth streaming preset        
            //_job.ApplyPreset(LivePresets.VC1HighSpeedBroadband4x3);

            // Creates the publishing format for the job
            PullBroadcastPublishFormat format = new PullBroadcastPublishFormat();
            format.BroadcastPort = 9090;
            format.MaximumNumberOfConnections = 50;

            // Adds the publishing format to the job
            _job.PublishFormats.Add(format);

            // Starts encoding
            _job.StartEncoding();
        }
        //webCamCtrl.StartCapture();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLogFile(this.GetType().Name, "button1_Click", ex.Message.ToString());
    }

}
```

I am using MediaElement to show the webcam both on my server and client systems.

on Client Side

```
try
            {

                theMainWindow.getServerIPAddress();
                IP = theMainWindow.machineIP;
                MediaElement1.Source = new Uri("http://" + IP + ":9090/");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

Comment: If you run a bandwidth test (say [SpeedTest.net](http://speedtest.net)) what are your upload and download speeds?

Answer (score 0):

you could propably use IIS Smooth Streaming to start playback with lower bitrate material and gradually increase it as your client buffer fills up. Silverlight has builtin support for Smooth Streaming and the same could be implemented by hand in WPF (at least theoritecally).

Is there any particular thing stopping you from using SL on client side?